# Finding example of metric space where you can determine the structure of a metric space with hausdorff metric.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and define $K(X, d) = \{A \subseteq X : A \neq \emptyset$ and $A$ is compact in $(X, d)\}$. Let $d_h : K(X, d) \times K(X, d) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be Hausdorff distance. We know that then $(K(X, d), d_h)$ is a metric space.

My question is this:

Find an example of a metric space $(X, d)$ so that we can determine that $(K(X, d), d_h)$ is isomorphic to some well known metric space. In particular, I want to find a metric space $(X, d)$ such that $K(X, d)$ is isomorphic to $([0, 1], d_2)$ where $d_2$ is euclidean metric on $\mathbb{[0, 1]}$. Since it seems to me that such metric space  doesn't even exist (although I'm not sure how to prove it). Any example where we know the structure of $K(X, d)$ would be great.

Only example where I was able to determine the structure of $K(X,d)$ is this:

Let $X$ be a finite set, in particular $X = \{x_1,...,x_n\}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $d : X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a discrete metric on $X$. Then every subset of $X$ is finite so it is compact, therefore $K(X, d) = \mathcal{P}(X)$. Suppose $A,B \subseteq X$ and $A \neq B$. Without loss of generality we can suppose there exists $x \in A \setminus B$. Now for every $y \in B$ we have $d(x, y) = 1$. From this and the fact that $d$ is discrete metric we can conclude $d_h(A, B) = 1$. Since $d_h$ is a metric, if $A = B$ we have $d_h(A, B) = 0$, therefore we have shown $d_h$ is a discrete metric.
It is easy to show now that $(K(X, d), d_h)$ is isomorphic to $(Y, d^{'})$ where $Y = \{y_1,...,y_{2^n}\}$ and $d'$ is discrete metric.

Comment: For an explicit example, when $X$ is the Cantor space, $K(X)$ is the Cantor space again

Comment: I also think that $K(X)$ is never isomorphic to $[0,1]$: when $X$ is compact connected $K(X)$ is infinite dimensional, and when $X$ is disconnected the disconnectedness should be inherited by $K(X)$

Comment: When $X$ is compact metric, even though $K(X)$ is huge as mentioned above, the closed subspace $C(X)\subseteq K(X)$ of compact connected subspaces of $X$ is much more well behaved and there are explicit geometric models for it in nice cases. For example $C([0,1])$ is homeomorphic to a closed disk in $\Bbb R^2$

Comment: Thank you very much, I was not aware of this facts. Can you suggest any literature where i can find proofs to some of these or some more proporties in general that hausdorff metric has?

Comment: *suggest any literature* --- See the comments to [Applications of Hausdorff distance and 'hyper-topologies](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3877841/13130). A useful introductory account can be found in [**Point Sets**](https://eudml.org/doc/276998) by Eduard Čech (1969) -- see Chapter III, specifically pp. 121-124 and some of the exercises on p. 135.

Comment: @Goki for $K(C)\cong C$ when $C$ is the Cantor space, this is exercise 7.11 in Kechris *Classical Descriptive Set Theory* (the idea is to use the characterization in 7.4). Everything else can be found in *Hyperspaces* by Wanes-Nadler, infinite dimensionality of $K(X)$ for compact connected $X$ is 14.12, while geometric models for $C(X)$ take up the whole of chapter II