# A continuous function with uncountable image between Polish spaces is injective on a generic compact set

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, polish-spaces

Exercise 8.8ii in Kechris *Classical Descriptive Set Theory* asks to prove that if $f\colon X\to Y$ is a continuous function between Polish spaces such that $f(X)$ is uncountable, then there is a Cantor set $C\subseteq X$ such $f\upharpoonright C$ is injective (this is one way to prove that $\mathbf{\Sigma}^1_1(Y)$ sets have the perfect set property).

I know how to build *one* such Cantor set by using a carefully constructed Cantor scheme on $X$, however the hints at the end of the book suggest showing that $\{K\in K(X)\mid f\upharpoonright K \text{ is injective}\}$ is a dense $G_\delta$ set in $K(X)$, the hyperspace of compact sets equipped with the Vietoris topology (this solves 8.8ii by combining it with 8.8i: the compact perfect sets are also a dense $G_\delta$ in $K(X)$).

It's not clear to me how to do this, hence my question: How do you prove that if $f\colon X\to Y$ is a continuous function between Polish spaces such that $f(X)$ is uncountable, then $\{K\in K(X)\mid f\upharpoonright K\text{ is injective}\}$ is a dense $G_\delta$ set in $K(X)$?

Comment: How did you solve the earlier exercise that the perfect subsets are a $G_\delta$ in $K(X)$?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma it's a bit long to write out all the details, but it's very similar to [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160095/the-collection-of-all-compact-perfect-subsets-is-g-delta-in-the-hyperspace-of) by Brian Scott here

Comment: It's enough for the 8.8i to show that the open sets used in the $G_\delta$ proof are themselves dense (by Baire).